# Power button count in given time

Tags: android

I  successfully developed android app which count power-button press with the help of **receiver class** and running in background  with **update-service class** and now i want to insert record to database when anybody press-power button 3 to 5 times **quickly** (in seconds may be 2 to 4 sec). All working fine but problem is service running in background so it will count when user casually  press power-button(i.e to phone screen on and off). So, How to stop that counting  casual or normal power-button press.
also my question is as service running in background can i reset service to create a fresh request whenever user want to insert record.
Thanks in Advance !
Here is my code :-

Home

```
   {Home.this.startService(new Intent(Home.this, UpdateService.class));}
```

My UpdateService

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();

      //register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);     
        mReceiver = new MyReceiver(UpdateService.this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);




 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {

     unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
     Log.i("onDestroy Reciever", "Called");
     super.onDestroy();

 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
```

}

MyReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static int countPowerOff=0;
 private boolean screenOff;
 private UpdateService updateservice=null;

public MyReceiver (UpdateService UpdateService)
{
       this.updateservice=UpdateService;             
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
        {
        countPowerOff++
        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
        { 
        }
     if(countPowerOff > 3)
        {
         //record insert 
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Make a public method in your service:

```
    private int counter = 0;

    private CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counter = 0;
        }
    };

    public void count(){
        counter++;
        if (counter == 3) {
            //do your staff
            return;
        }

        timer.cancel();
        timer.start();
   }
```

and in your receiver in onReceive() method just call service.count()

By the way, screen may turn off even if user does not push power button. Also, you count only every second push - when screen is off, pushing the power button turns it on, but you don't count. Why don't you just handle power button pushes? It requires

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

permission. The code is:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("111", "keydown: " + event.getKeyCode());
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            //call service.count()
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir, but my application is running in background so it will listen power button even application is closed.i think **onKeyDown** will only works when application is opened

Comment: you can make invisible alert dialog above all views on the screen and catch any keydown event in it. I develop a screenlock application and it works. You also can dismiss it when you want. I use this HomeKeyLocker: https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker/blob/master/HomeLockerLib/src/main/java/io/github/homelocker/lib/HomeKeyLocker.java

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hander callback to implement a reset of the click counter.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    private static final int POWER_OFF_TIMEOUT = 500;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable powerOffCounterReset = new PowerOfTimeoutReset();

    private int countPowerOff = 0;
    private boolean screenOff;
    private UpdateService updateService = null;


    public MyReceiver (UpdateService updateService) {
         this.updateService = updateService;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) { 
         countPowerOff++  
       } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) { } 

      if(countPowerOff > 3) { 
            //record insert 
           countPowerOff = 0; 
           canclePowerOffTimeout(); 
      } else { 
           resetPowerOffTimeout();
      }
    }

    private void resetPowerOffTimeout() {
          canclePowerOffTimeout();
          startPowerOffTimeout();
    }

    private void startPowerOffTimeout() {
         handler.postDelayed( powerOffCounterReset, POWER_OFF_TIMEOUT );
    }

    private void canclePowerOffTimeout() {
        handler.removeCallback( powerOffCounterReset );
    }


    private class PowerOfTimeoutReset implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            countPowerOff = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you give any idea sir

Comment: I thought giving the right idea for solving the issue will be more useful than yust posting the Code that will du the job.

Comment: thanks sir, but on every request of power-button press it will goes to else condition if(countPowerOff > 3) else and call **resetPowerOffTimeout();**

Comment: Yes, but this is required to have the requested behaviour